# Split String into Array with No Delimiter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a string like `s = "abcdefgh"`. I want to split it by number of characters like:

```
a(0)="ab"
a(1)="cd"
a(2)="ef"
a(3)="gh"
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What is your criteria for splitting?  Every time the character changes?  Every second character?

Comment: Example isn't clear. Do you want to split per 2 chars or split whenever the next char isn't identical to the previous one?

Comment: How would you split "abbcdccceeee", for example? (Your question doesn't say much about what you're trying to do...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to split into two-character groups:

```
Dim parts = Regex.Matches(s, ".{2}").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value)
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/ZVL2a (C#)

Comment: The `[…]` around the `Select` is unnecessary. Otherwise, this is how I’d do it as well. Just pay attention that `.` doesn’t match *every* character unless you specify the `SingleLine` flag.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks.  I wrote it in C# first and used an online converter.  I'm not very good with VB.Net :)  Strangely enough, when I tried to do a VB.Net sample, I got internal errors and a note about `System.Linq` not being a valid library: http://ideone.com/KlCAu.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The VB.NET compiler for Mono is unfortunately a lost cause. It is **completely** unusable. I find that a pity since I originally come from VB but I don’t foresee the situation changing soon so you are essentially forced to use C# if you want to write for non-Windows platforms. That said, your VB code on ideone contains a small error, the `part as var` is wrong, it should just be `For Each part`, or alternatively `… part As Match` (and then the `Cast` would be unnecessary). But that won’t fix the internal compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Linq method that doesn't require writing a loop:

```
    Const splitLength As Integer = 2
    Dim a = Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length \ splitLength).
        Select(Function(i) s.Substring(i * splitLength, splitLength))
```

Comment: +1 I was in the middle of writing the exact same thing. Do realize this will blow up on odd-length strings (as most of the other answers as well)

Comment: @lc Are you sure? I tested it on 2, 3, 4, 5 & 6 and it always seemed to work okay. The only problem I found was if the original string's length wasn't an exact multiple of the split length – in which case the last few characters were omitted.

Comment: Actually you're right, it won't blow up (I was thinking of using a ceiling function to get the last bit). It *will* however omit the last short bit as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting every 2 chars, is what I think you wanted

```
    Dim s As String = "aabbccdd"

    For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1 Step 1
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(i, 2))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Why don’t you simply increment in steps of 2 instead of using the additional check?

Comment: Yea that would be even better

Answer (score 0):

I you would use a `List(Of String)` instead, it simplifies it:

```
Dim s = "aabbccdde" ' yes, it works also with an odd number of chars '
Dim len = 2
Dim list = New List(Of String)
For i = 0 To s.Length - 1 Step len
    Dim part = If(i + len > s.Length, s.Substring(i), s.Substring(i, len))
    list.Add(part)
Next
Dim result = list.ToArray() ' if you really need that array '
```